# Is there any statement/function in java which can execute the previous body if the condition becomes false?

Tags: java

I am generating a random number and if it is odd I print "hello" but if it is even I want the pogram to re-execute the program till an odd number is produced instead of finishing.

Comment: Take a look at while loops (or do-while).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `do-while` loop repeats while *true*, so you can just invert the condition:

```
int num;
do {
    num = /* generate number */;
}
while (num % 2 != 1); // While *not* odd, keep looping
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
boolean isnotODD = false;
do{
   //generate your number
   //check if your number is odd or not
   if(check_if_your_number_is_odd){
       isnotODD = true;
   }
} while(!isnotODD);
```

Comment: I'm confused. ` if(your_number_is_odd){ isnotODD = true; }` says if the number _is_ odd, then "is _not_ odd" is true. Huh?

Comment: what did you mean @LewBloch ?

Comment: I mean that your code says two opposite things and that's confusing.

Comment: i mean `if(check_if_your_number_is_odd){}` or not, if yes then it change `isnotODD to true` its my pleasure to correct it @LewBloch :)